# Create dynamic view of some data

Tags: android

How to create dynamic view of some data getting from database like in below picture. In below pic, first line consist of 1 view, second line consist of 2 view similarly 3rd line has 1 view and fourth line 2 view. like in below pic.[image]

I know well that how to create a layout using java like this code,

```
final int N = 10; // total number of textviews to add

final TextView[] myTextViews = new TextView[N]; // create an empty array;

for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    // create a new textview
    final TextView rowTextView = new TextView(this);

    // set some properties of rowTextView or something
    rowTextView.setText("This is row #" + i);

    // add the textview to the linearlayout
    myLinearLayout.addView(rowTextView);

    // save a reference to the textview for later
    myTextViews[i] = rowTextView;
}
```

but i want to know how each line different to each other.

Comment: Look at linear layout. Hint: you can put a horizontal linear layout inside a vertical one.

Comment: please see attached picture.

Comment: why not using RecyclerView with gridLayout and odd position has 1 span and even has 2 span?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 1 : Along with your TextViews, create a container layout like a LinearLayout for each line programatically.

Step 2 : So each LinearLayout with a horizontal orientation should represent a Line.

Step 3 : Add your views to the LinearLayout.
Then add all the LinearLayouts into a parent view like another LinearLayout with vertical orientation

Example :

```
final int N = 10; // total number of Lines to add
LinearLayout llContainer = new LinearLayout(this);
llContainer.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    LinearLayout llLine = new LinearLayout(this);
    llLine.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);  
    //Make other configurations for the linear layout
    //Since you want 1 and 2 views in each line alternatively you could do this
    if(i%2 ==0){
    //Add one view for all even lines
    //Whatever view you need. Im using a textview.
    TextView tv = new TextView(this);
    //Make your configurations/setText etc
    llLine.addView(tv);
    }else{
    TextView tv1 = new TextView(this);
    TextView tv2 = new TextView(this);
    llLine.addView(tv1);
    llLine.addView(tv2);
    }
    llContainer.addView(llLine);
}
```

Something like this. I have not tested the above code. It is an example and it should work. Hope this helped.

Cheers!